Django inline formset creates empty items and I don't know where they come from
I've been struggling for days to make my django admin inline work properly. It works fine but when I add an additional item on django admin web interface it does save the item but adds one additional item with the same field values except for offer_select value. The latter is always empty. Why does that happen? What am I doing wrong?
class OfferInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    offer_select = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Offer.objects.all(),
                                          label='Offer_select')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OfferInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if instance:
            self.initial['offer_select'] = instance.id

    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('offer_select', 'partner', 'logotype', 'number', 'visible')

@admin.register(Feed)
class FeedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class OfferItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Offer
        form = OfferInlineForm
        extra = 0

    list_display = ('name', 'utm_source', 'number',)
    ordering = ('name', 'number')
    inlines = (OfferItemInline,)
    fields = ('name',)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        feed = form.instance
        for instance in instances:
            for data in formset.cleaned_data:
                offer_select = data.get('offer_select')
                offer_current = data.get('id')
                partner = data.get('partner')
                logotype = data.get('logotype')
                visible = data.get('visible')
                number = data.get('number')
                if offer_select != offer_current:
                    instance.feed = None
                    instance.save()
                offer_select.feed = feed
                offer_select.partner = partner
                offer_select.logotype = logotype
                offer_select.number = number
                offer_select.visible = visible
                offer_select.save()
        formset.save()


The reason can be, how you are handling form data in the save_formset method. You're setting self.initial['offer_select'] to instance.id, but offer_select is supposed to be a ModelChoiceField referring to another Offer instance, not the ID of the current instance.
The save_formset method is complex. You iterate over each instance in the instances and you iterate over formset. It may misapplied data assignments and creating new records unintentionally.
class OfferInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
offer_select = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Offer.objects.all(), label='Offer_select')

class Meta:
    model = Offer
    fields = ('offer_select', 'partner', 'logotype', 'number', 'visible')


@admin.register(Feed)
class FeedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class OfferItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Offer
        form = OfferInlineForm
        extra = 0

    list_display = ('name', 'utm_source', 'number',)
    ordering = ('name', 'number')
    inlines = (OfferItemInline,)
    fields = ('name',)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for form, instance in zip(formset.forms, instances):
            if form.cleaned_data:
                offer_select = form.cleaned_data.get('offer_select')
                if offer_select:
                    instance.partner = form.cleaned_data.get('partner', instance.partner)
                    instance.logotype = form.cleaned_data.get('logotype', instance.logotype)
                    instance.number = form.cleaned_data.get('number', instance.number)
                    instance.visible = form.cleaned_data.get('visible', instance.visible)
                    instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()

